# Spring/Hibernate/Junit example of testing DAO against HSQLDB

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, junit, hsqldb

I'm working on trying to implement a *JUnit* test to check the functionality of a DAO.  (The DAO will create/read a basic object/table relationship).

The trouble I'm having is the persistence of the DAO (for the non-test code) is being completed through an in-house solution using *Spring/Hibernate*, which eliminates the usual `*.hbm.xml`templates that most examples I have found contain.

Because of this, I'm having some trouble understanding how to setup a *JUnit* test to implement the DAO to create/read (just very basic functionality) to an in-memory *HSQLDB*.  I have found a few examples, but the usage of the in-house persistence means I can't extend some of the classes the examples show (I can't seem to get the application-context.xml setup properly).

Can anyone suggest any projects/examples I could take a look at (or any documentation) to further my understanding of the best way to implement this test functionality?  I feel like this should be really simple, but I keep running into problems implementing the examples I have found.

**edit:**

Here's my solution for better readability, for anyone who needs a hand getting things going:

- My `TestClass`:

  ```
  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
  @ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:applicationContextTest-Example.xml")
  @Transactional
  public class ExampleDaoTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
      @Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
      private SessionFactory exampleSessionFactory;

      @Resource(name = "exampleDao")
      private ExampleDao exampleDao;
  ```
- My `applicationContext.xml` file:

  ```
  <!-- List of Daos to be tested -->
  <bean id="exampleDao" class="org.myExample.ExampleDao"/>

  <!-- Datasource -->
  <bean id="example_dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:ExampleTest"/>
      <property name="username" value="sa"/>
      <property name="password" value=""/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Session Factory -->
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="example_dataSource"/>
      <property name="annotatedClasses">
          <list>
              <value>org.myExample.ExampleClass</value>
          </list>
      </property>
      <property name="hibernateProperties">
          .... left to user to choose properties
      </property>
  </bean>
  ```

Comment: Some additional info:  I'm not too experienced with the configuration of Spring/Hibernate, I've had them already configured in previous projects until now.

My current project is a mishmash of configurations, I can't figure out just how the "in-house" class I referred to obtains its session factory.  All the DAOs extend it (an abstract class), and within is an abstract declaration:  
public abstract SessionFactory getSessionFactory();
I can't figure out where the "getSessionFactory()" method comes from.  I think it must be injected by Spring somehow, but I can't find any config files doing so.

Comment: Thanks guys, you've all been helpful.
For those in the future:
I included into my unit test (via @ContextConfiguration as Willie specifies) my applicationContext-Test.xml file in which I defined an HSQLDB datasource, session factory, transaction manager, and the Daos as beans <bean id="myDao" class="org.mine.MyDao"/>.  My Test class is annotated with: @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class),
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "your appContext.xml")
@Transactional, and my session factory & dao are annotated as resources (from .xml defs):  @Resource(name = "sessionFactory")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring 3 offers a new `jdbc` namespace that includes support for embedded databases, including HSQLDB. So that takes care of that part.

I'm wondering what the "in-house solution" could be. You can use annotations (either JPA or Hibernate annotations) to ORM your domain objects, so why do you need an "in-house solution"? E.g.:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
    p:packagesToScan="myapp.model" />
```

As far as implementing a test goes, use Spring's TestContext Framework. A test can look like this (again I'm assuming Spring 3 below, though it should work in Spring 2.5 simply by changing @Inject to @Autowired):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({
    "/beans-datasource-it.xml",
    "/beans-dao.xml",
    "/beans-service.xml",
    "/beans-web.xml" })
@Transactional
public class ContactControllerIT {
    @Inject private ContactController controller;

    ... setUp() and tearDown() ...

    @Test
    public void testGetContact() {
        String viewName = controller.getContact(request, 1L, model);

        ... assertions ...
    }
}
```

You'd put the embedded database inside `beans-datasource-it.xml`, for example. ('it' here stands for integration test, and the files are on the classpath.) The controller in this example lives in `beans-web.xml`, and will be autowired into the `ContactController` field.

That's just an outline of what to do but hopefully it's enough to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

[See here](http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=118). It assumes maven2 as build tool, but you can easily use anything.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently implemented a similar solution in some of my code using *Hibernate*, *Spring* and *HSQLDB.*

Its is worth noting that `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`  has now be deprecated - but it is still pretty straight forward to test - I cover most the details here: http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/05/hibernate-spring-testing-dao-layer-with.html

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line with hibernate is the `SessionFactory` - your in-house solution will most likely be creating one of these somehow. Find out how, and then add a bean to create one in your test app context in the same way (or if possible using your in-house code that is used at runtime.). You may need to create your own [FactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) to do the instantiation. (Use [AbstractFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AbstractFactoryBean.html) as your base class.)

Once this is in place, most of the examples using LocalSessionFactoryBean can be migrated to your situation - instead of using LocalsessionFactoryBean, use your custom factory bean.

(If you've not done so already, look at the [Testing](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/testing.html) section in the spring reference - it makes testing with Spring, and injecting tests with beans from the context a breeze.)

Answer (score 0):

My application context looks a bit different

```
<beans:bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="HSQL_DS">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:Test"/>
    <beans:property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <beans:property name="password" value=""/>
</beans:bean>
<jdbc:embedded-database id="HSQL_DS">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/>
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:data.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

and my test class looks like this:

```
public class Tester {

    private EmbeddedDatabase db;

    @Before
     public void setUp(){
        db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().addDefaultScripts().build();


    }

    @Test
    public void TestMe(){
        System.out.println("Testing");
    }


    @After
    public void tearDown(){

        db.shutdown();
    }
}
```