# Hibernate temporary datastore

Tags: spring, hibernate

I doing unit testing on spring-hibernate DAOs... configured using

`@ContextConfiguration(
     locations = { 
      "classpath:test-applicationContext.xml" 
   })`

but it looks like its transacting with the actual database. 
How do I use a temporary datastore with out working on actual database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your data store on a separate file and include that xml file with your mail application xml. When testing, include a separate xml file to hold your data store pointing to another database such as hsql. Then this will be the data source referred to by your main applicationContext.xml.

Comment: But if I use Postgres in test application context then do I need Postgres installed on to run the test ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys I used H2 and got it working:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:h2:mem:processdb;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:create.sql'" />
</bean>




<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="stateDAO" class="com.tutorial.jquery.dao.impl.StateDAOImpl"></bean>
<bean id="stateService" class="com.tutorial.jquery.service.impl.StateServiceImpl"></bean>
```